# SubSonic: Selecting all columns with an aggregate

Tags: c#, subsonic2.2

How would you best handle constructing this SQL statement in SubSonic?

```
SELECT ac.*
       , SUM(pt.amount) AS totalPoints
FROM tbl_account AS ac
     INNER JOIN tbl_pointTracking AS pt ON ac.id = pt.accountID
GROUP BY pt.accountID
ORDER BY totalPoints DESC;
```

I know how to handle aggregates, but not sure how to handle aggregates with other columns.

Thanks all,
-Steve

Comment: Will do! I'll go back and do such now....

Sorry about that.

Comment: BAM! 54%, yo. The others I can't mark as answers, because I never got an answer for them. Anyone know the answer for above?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which will help you to do so.

```
  gvGroup.DataSource = office.DB.Select(SubSonic.Aggregate.GroupBy("Designation"), SubSonic.Aggregate.Count("Designation")).From(Of office.Employee).ExecuteDataSet
        gvGroup.DataBind()
```